# Can we replace an integer to English letter in a document python

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a document and it contain numbers in between is there a way I can replace all the numbers to the English equivalent ?

eg:

`My age is 10. I am in my 7th grade.`

expected-o/p :

`My age is Ten and I am in my seventh grade.`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [num2words](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words).

You'll have to construct regexp to catch the numbers you want to replace and pass them to `num2words`. Based on example provided, you also might need the `ordinal` flag.

```
import re
from num2words import num2words

# this is just an example NOT ready to use code

text = "My age is 10. I am in my 7th grade."
to_replace = set(re.findall('\d+', text))         # find numbers to replace
longest = sorted(to_replace, key=len, reverse=True)  # sort so longest are replaced first
for m in longest:
  n = int(m)                       # convert from string to number
  result = num2words(n)            # generate text representation
  text = re.sub(m, result, text)          # substitute in the text
print(text)
```

edited to reflect that OP wants to catch all digits

Comment: sorry forgot to change 10 to ten in my expected output in my question.

Comment: Then remove the `(?=th)` from the regex search string.